# How to install ruby and rails on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have try so many tutorial to install ruby and rails. In my pc ruby version 1.9+ and rails is 2. I want to install ruby and rails with version rails 4.0.1 something like that so bundla install automatically. I am facing problem with rail 2.0.0 when I create a new project with this command

```
rails new blogs
```

then it's create a new folder instead of blogs folder and stu is also not new.

Please give me right tutorial where i can install rails with new version my ubuntu is 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Why the downvotes? It's an honest question. When I learned Rails, I used these resources:

- http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book to install Ruby and Rails on Mac OS X (there are instructions for Ubuntu, too)
- http://railsforzombies.org to know how Rails works (it's a good beginner tutorial)
- http://tryruby.org to know about Ruby

Other than that I suggest using Google a lot: Google "how to install Rails on ubuntu". There's several pages of tutorials there. As a developer it is normal to Google 50++ times a day. (I think I'm closer to 500, actually.) When Google doesn't return anything, that's when you go to Stack Overflow. Also, try to find someone who knows how Rails works (check Google for Rails events in your country) so you can ask them, it's easier to get taught Rails in real life than on the Internet because there's a lot of things to set up.

Edit: So I checked your profile, you ask a lot of basic questions. It seems that you really need to find someone to teach you this. It's normal to have a lot of errors at the start, that is how programming works. But use Google first. Just get used to the idea that most of the time, you will need to solve things by yourself.

Comment: I am using ubanto Please check this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747258/install-rvm-bash-root-rvm-scripts-rvm-no-such-file-or-directory