# install rvm "bash /root/.rvm/scripts/rvm No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to install RVM in ubuntu and I am following these steps

```
root@jaskaran-Vostro-1550:/home/user_name# sudo apt-get install curl
```

done this successfully

```
root@jaskaran-Vostro-1550:/home/user_name# curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

done this successfully

but when I run this command

```
root@jaskaran-Vostro-1550:/home/user_name# source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

result like that

```
bash: /root/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

What's wrong in this?

Answer (score 10):

I was installing RVM on a remote server today and had the same issue. It seems that the installation was not executed by default. This is what I did to solve it:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

  # In case rvm not found
  cd ~/.rvm/archives
  tar xvzf rvm-1.26.0.tgz # or whatever RVM version you have
  cd mpapis-rvm-xxxxxxx
  ./install
  cd ..
  rm -Rf mpapis-rvm-xxxxxxxx

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 10):

If you installed rvm from root, try:

```
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Answer (score 8):

Try looking in `/usr/local/rvm` instead.  You're root, it installs differently as root.

Are you sure you want to install RVM as root?  It's typically a user thing.

Comment: For me it had installed in /usr/local/rvm, but when I run the command source /home/{username}/.rvm/scripts/rvm it again says not found. But I wanted this to be installed on the user, which when tried gives error as unsafe user.

Answer (score 5):

The scripts folder is inside the zipped directory, so first we need to extract it and then run the command. Do the following things.

```
cd ~/.rvm/archives
tar xvzf rvm-1.26.0.tgz # or whatever RVM version you have
```

This will extract the folder, and in this, there will be a folder named scripts. Now run the following command.

```
source ~/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.26.11/scripts/rvm
```

And you are done.

Answer (score 1):

me too got the same issue and get it resolved by simply **changing my user from root to another normal user**, i'm using ubuntu subsystem in windows 10